# Reducing check time of R package

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm currently working on reducing the check time of an R package. Using `devtools::check()` on the package root directory, these are the longest parts:

> ✔  creating vignettes (44.3s) 
> ✔  checking whether package ‘DIscBIO’ can be installed (21.2s) 
> ✔  checking R code for possible problems (21.8s) 
> ✔  checking for code/documentation mismatches (16s)

Regarding the vignette, I don't know what I can do to further reduce creation time. All R chunks are under `eval=FALSE`, all images have been cut out, 1/3 of the vignette is gone, and the check time won't budge. Should it really take 45 seconds for an i7 CPU to build a 500-line .Rmd vignette?

As for the rest, I really don't know what I can do. What exactly is checked in these steps? What can I do to reduce check times in those stages?

I'm running out of things to trim, and the biggest issue I have with this particular package is the fact that it has *so* many imports (28), but I can't get rid of them without dropping major or essential functionality.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce check time? These timings don't seem too bad to me.

Comment: @Roland they're indeed fine on my machine (total check time < 3 min), but on win-builder.r-project.org/ the whole thing is taking over 15 minutes (matching the check time CRAN reviewers are reporting). I was gonna post those check times, but win-builder seems to be all queued up since yesterday. Anyway, my rationale is that if I can reduce the posted times by half I might achieve a reasonable check time on the remote server.

Comment: 15 minutes is quite long. My package (that also includes a vignette) takes about 4 minutes on CRAN's machines. That's the same timings as on my local machine. Such a mismatch is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the vignette takes up considerable time, instead of tweaking and cutting it, maybe you could just exclude it from the check process by running `devtools::check(vignettes = FALSE)` (if that's an option for you). From the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/2.3.0/topics/check):

> If `FALSE`, do not build or check vignettes

As for the other checks you pointed out, I'm afraid there's little room for improvement.